# php chmod issue with server

Tags: php, cpanel, chmod

I am creating new directory with one index.php file inside, with PHP script.
To give privileges I am using this code -

```
mkdir("".$directoryName."");
chmod($directoryName.',755);
chmod($directoryName.'/index.php',644);
```

When I am working with my local machine it is working fine. But, if I move code to server, privileges are not set. By default it set to as 0777 for directory and 0666 for index.php.

Here is the hierarchy -

```
public_html/{mydirectory}/index.php
```

`public_html` is having 0755. 
The controller file from which I am setting permissions is located at -

```
public_html/{directory}/{directory}/{directory}/controller.php
```

All the {directory} has 0755 permissions. I have checked with changing permissions of all these {directory} to 0777, but same issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: On my linux server, I have to put in the 0 in the mode to force octal mode, so chmod($directoryName.',0755); instead of chmod($directoryName.',755);, etc.